# Programming Python O'Reilly webserver.py Permission Denied

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, cgi, permission-denied

I'm trying to learn CGI scripting throw the book "Programming Python" 4th editon by O'Reilly, but I'm stuck at running my first CGI scripting. For learning porpuses the book suggests using an HTTP Server script called webserver.py as shown below.

```
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
webdir = '.'
port = 80
if len(sys.argv) > 1: webdir = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) > 2: port = int(sys.argv[2])
print('webdir "%s", port %s' % (webdir, port))
os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = ('', port)
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

There is no problem acessing the server throw the browser by typing 'http://localhost', but when I try to run the cgi script inside the folder 'cgi-bin' an permission denied error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 1143, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

As said in the book this problem can be solved by changing the permission of the file, to do so I typed 'chmod 755 cgi1.py' on the terminal and change the file permission to the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pedro pedro 209 Ago 26 20:09 cgi1.py
```

But I keep getting the same error. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits, running the HTTP server file with 'sudo python3 webserver.py', does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running the command with `sudo`, it is running as `root` and not as `pedro`. It could be that the script is assuming some other role (this is possible since you are running as root). Try removing `sudo`, and/or running the server on a different port, like `8080`.

You might also try adding the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the very top of your file, `cgi1.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, When I try running the webserver.py without sudo it gives me an 'Permission Denied' error. The cgi1.py script already has the line '#!/usr/bin/env python' as its first line of code. About changing the port, it doesn't seen to have any effect on the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You tried on a non-privileged port, i.e. greater than 1024 ?